# Is there a way to integrate task into Azure Devops server?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML task that runs tests on .NET solutions in Azure pipeline.
It is meant to run after a build step and execute Unit-tests on that assembly.
The output is a simple XML file with test results that needs to be shown after each build run in the summary tab.

How can I make it recognizable by azure?
For example: MsBuild step is recognized and shown in the summary menu as Build Artifacts and have the option to download them from Azure UI. How can I make Azure recognize my task and show it's artifacts and info too? How many tests ran and info in the title and when I click drop it will show artifacts

Summary menu after build run on Azure DevOps server

[image]

Comment: Hi @David Bulg did you try out below solution, Please let me know if there is any question?

Comment: Yes, I found out about the echos that Azure can catch, the same for other reports.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `##vso[task.uploadsummary]local file path` to upload summary to the build summary. However you may need to write the contents of xml file into md file. please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#addattachment-attach-a-file-to-the-build) to learn more upload tasks.

```
- powershell: '##vso[task.uploadsummary]path to test result'
```

However test results isnot intended to be displayed on the summary page.

You must have noticed that there is a **Test** tab beside **Summary** tab. Usually the test results will be automatically published by Vstest tasks and the test results will be displayed in Test tab.

You can also publish your test results using task **PublishTestResults** as mentioned by @4c74356b41. You test results will then be displayed in Test tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to make your test results visible in the build summary, there is [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) meant for that specifically.

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit' # Options: JUnit, NUnit, VSTest, xUnit, cTest
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
```

your test results should be compatible with one of the supported versions